# Laravel Env file : How to add a file path which contain space

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel project I need to setup the path to Chrome.exe in env
tried `CHROME_PATH='C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'`
But composer update cause error

```
Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
 @php artisan package:discover --ansi
The environment file is invalid!
Failed to parse dotenv file due to an unexpected escape sequence. Failed at ['C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'].
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

how to solve it ?

Answer (score 6):

@Sehdev answer didn't work for me 
But after searches for hours I found this [answer](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/170#issuecomment-538356890) and it solved my problem
Here is the solution

```
WKHTMLTOPDF="\"\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"\""
```

Elegant solution
Try use Encode it with base64 and when ever using it decode it in config file `base64_decode(env('WKHTMLTOPDF'))`

example : `C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe` when encode it to base 64 be : `QzpcXFByb2dyYW0gRmlsZXNcXHdraHRtbHRvcGRmXFxiaW5cXHdraHRtbHRvcGRmLmV4ZQ==`

without any space

Comment: It looks bad but it works!

Comment: yes try  to use encode and decode for a better solution you can use encode base64

Answer (score 4):

`\` is known as [Escape sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) that is used to escape something.

**Change**

```
CHROME_PATH='C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
```

**to**

```
CHROME_PATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
```

**OR**

Escape them using `\`( escape)

```
CHROME_PATH="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
```